# jQuery trying to insert HTML of another div dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is really hard to explain. I have some divs with an id within a table

```
<table id="dgAvailable">
  <tr> <td> <div id="HEYD"> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <div id="HANW"> </td> </tr> 
</table>
```

i need to fill those divs with this content

```
<div class="evenprop"><h3>Hanworth</h3><span class="locid" style="display:none">HANW</span></div>
<div class="evenprop"><h3>Heydon</h3><span class="locid" style="display:none">HEYD</span></div>
```

so i need to get the div which contains the locid with same id as my other div and then insert that html within the div in the table dgAvailable

```
$('#dgAvailable > tr > td > div').each(function(){
  if $(this).attr('id') = $('.evenprop > .locid').attr('id') {
  $(this).html() = $('.evenprop > .locid').parent().html()
});
```

I really have no other way of describing this?

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: it's ok :) I'll just point out then that you need parenthesis around your if-statement test (e.g. `if ($(this).attr('id') == true) { }')`. You also need to use `==` or `===` (instead of `=`) in your comparison, otherwise you're trying assignment instead of an equivalence test. And you're also missing a `}` (should be `}});` at the end there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.evenprop .locid").each(function() {
   $("#" + this.innerHTML).html($(this).parent().clone());
});
```

[You can try out a demo against your markup here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eXX23/).

---

If you have control over that other markup, you can clean it up a great deal by using a data attribute, like this:

```
<div class="evenprop" data-locid="HANW"><h3>Hanworth</h3></div>
<div class="evenprop" data-locid="HEYD"><h3>Heydon</h3></div>
```

Then your jQuery also gets a bit simpler, like this:

```
$("div.evenprop").each(function() {
   $("#" + $(this).attr('data-locid')).html($(this).clone());
});
```

Or if you don't need the old node and just want to move it, use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), like this:

```
$("div.evenprop").each(function() {
   $("#" + $(this).attr('data-locid')).append(this);
});
```

Comment: @Jamie - I *think* this is what you mean, not following 100% though: `$("div.evenprop .locname").each(function() { $("#" + $("#ctl00_dd1").val()).html($(this).clone()); });`

Answer (score 4):

Should do it.

```
$('.locid').each(function(){
   $('#'+$.trim($(this).text())).html(this.parentNode.cloneNode(true));
});
```